# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfe' in file error happen

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfe' in file error happen.
 I wanna read tsv file,and change into csv file.When I run this app,this error happen.
I wrote

```
# coding: shift_jis

import libraries as libraries
import DataCleaning
import csv


media = 'Google'
tsv = csv.reader(file(r"data/aaa.csv"), delimiter = '\t',encoding='UTF-16')

for row in tsv:
  print ", ".join(row)
```

I think ASCII is wrong,but I do not know how to fix this.
My tsv file is  shift_jis and finally I wanna change it into UTF-8.But I think this error happen because I did not designate encoding as UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

The `csv` module on Python 2 is not Unicode friendly. You can't pass `encoding` to it as an argument, it's not a recognized argument (only `csv` format parameters are accepted as keyword arguments). It can't work with the Py2 `unicode` type correctly, so using it involves reading in binary mode, and even then, it only works properly when newlines are one byte per character. Per [the `csv` module docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

> Note: This version of the `csv` module doesn’t support Unicode input. Also, there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters. Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe; see the examples in section Examples.

If at all possible, switch to Python 3, where the `csv` module works with Py3's Unicode-friendly `str` by default, bypassing all the issues from Python 2's `csv` module, and `encoding` can be passed to `open` correctly. In that case, your code simplifies to:

```
with open(r"data/aaa.csv", encoding='utf-16', newline='') as inf:
    tsv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\t')
    # Explicit encoding argument may be needed for TextIOWrapper;
    # the rewrapping is done to ensure newline='' is used as the csv module requires
    csv.writer(io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, newline='')).writerows(tsv)
```

Or to write as CSV to a UTF-8 encoded file:

```
with open(r"data/aaa.csv", encoding='utf-16', newline='') as inf, open(outfilename, "w", encoding='utf-8', newline='') as outf:
    tsv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter='\t')
    csv.writer(outf).writerows(tsv)
```

Failing that, take a look at [the `unicodecsv` module on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv), which should handle Unicode input properly on Python 2.

Comment: thx ur comments.I changed my python into 3.6 version.And I wrote ur codes(ur second code).I got an error, NameError: name 'f' is not defined.In my code,in the part of f variable,Unresolved reference'f' and in the part of io variable,Unresolved reference'io'.

Comment: what should I do to fix it?

Comment: @user7664633: `f` was a typo on my part (I named the file object `inf` and used `f` by accident). `io` is a standard module; import it at the top of your file.